# How to override edgesIgnoringSafeArea (or any View modifier)

Tags: swift, swiftui, safearea

I'm trying to override the functionality of `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` since I have custom handling for the vertical safe area in my view. However, there's no super to call so I'm not sure how to proceed other then handling every safe area edge. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
// Will use later for custom handling of vertical safe area
@State private var edgesThatIgnoreSafeArea: Edge.Set = []

func edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_ edges: Edge.Set) -> some View {
    edgesThatIgnoreSafeArea = edges

    // There is no super here to call, and calling self would just call this function again
    return AnyView(edgesIgnoringSafeArea(edges.subtracting(.vertical)))  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot override modifiers, but we can add our own which use standard, like

```
extension View {
    func edgesIgnoringHorizontal(_ edges: Edge.Set) -> some View {
         self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(edges.subtracting(.vertical))
    }
}
```

*Note: although I don't see much sense in such `overriding`, because just using of `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)` is simpler and more obvious and readable... but anyway.*

Comment: Figured out a way to do the override. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this. I wrapped my view with `AnyView` and applied the selective safe area to it.

```
@State private var edgesThatIgnoreSafeArea: Edge.Set = []

func edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_ edges: Edge.Set) -> some View {
    edgesThatIgnoreSafeArea = edges

    return AnyView(self).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(edges.subtracting(.vertical))
}
```

Comment: Definitely open to feedback on this answer or different answers if anyone has a better approach.